# HTML - Bootstrap staggering columns

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below code and just want a simple 3 by 3 grid (am using paginate) of properties. However, as you can see by image, the first three are staggered, but the rest are fine. I've been looking at it so long now I probably can't see the wood for the trees. Any advice?

```
<div class="container">
 <br>
 <h2 style="text-align: left; color: #686868;">PROPERTIES FOR SALE</h2>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
 <% will_paginate @properties %>
  <% if @properties.present? %>
      <div class="row">
      <% @properties.each do |property| %>
          <br>
          <a href="/properties/show?property=<%= property.reference %>">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="color: white;">
              <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="row" style="display: flex;">
                <% property.pictures.first(1).each do |picture| %>
                      <img src="<%= picture.url %>" class="img-responsive center-block" style="max-height: 250px;"/>
                <% end %>
                </div>

                <div class="row" style="background-color: #2bb8d6;">
                  <div class="row" style="width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                    <h4><strong><p style="padding-left: 5%;"><%= property.price_text %></p></strong></h4>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row" style="background-color: #1b7b90;">
                  <strong>
                    <p style="padding-left: 5%; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0; margin: 0;">
                    <%= property.bedrooms %> Bedroom <%= property.property_type %> - <%= property.property_style %>
                    </p>
                  </strong>
                    <p style="padding-left: 5%"> <%= property.advert_heading %></p>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </a>

      <% end %>
      </div>

  <% else %>
      <p><h2>There are no properties containing the term <%= params[:search] %>.</h2></p>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row">
    <h4><strong><%= will_paginate @properties %></strong></h4>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: if you could use bootply or jsfiddle to reproduce your issue, people could help much easier.

Comment: Why do you have content inside of a row but outside of a column? You're not using Bootstrap's grid system correctly. You shouldn't be putting row divs in row divs or column divs immediately in column divs.

Comment: Could the `<br>` cause the issue? PS: I can also see you are nesting rows, why don't just use `col-sm-12` (I also see you are removing margin and padding with inline style on that nested row)

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid *Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.*

Answer (score 0):

Use flex on the main container, I believe is the main .row but you have to give it another class since you use .row in other cases. Lets say on the main .row container you have a class .row-flex, then:

```
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

and then give flex: 1 to the container of col-sm-4

```
.col-sm-4 {
 flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the first picture. or set a static width and height for each of the picture.Example:

```
img.propertyPic{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```